# How to get ASP.NET application path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have my owned siteMapProvider, I need phisical file path to initialize it but I can't use HttpContext to do that, because IIS 7 will thrown exception:

```
fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName);
```

How can I do MapPath without HttpContext?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Take a look at the following: [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx) (from MSDN)

Answer (score 5):

you can also try:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```

Comment: Please read my question: I can't use HttpContext to do that, because IIS 7 will thrown exception

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why does IIS 7 throw an exception?.