# Dynamics 365 WebAPI helper Configuration class doesn't find config file

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, iis-express

I have a solution that outputs data from a WCF service and reads it from a Dynamics 365 WebAPI.

The main project is a WCF service that is hosted in IIS. While debugging I use IIS Express.

I have a data layer project (dll) that has the CRM `WebAPI Helper Classes` imported within the project.

When I launch the debugger (IISExpress), the data layer will use the WebAPI `FileConfiguration` helper class to try and read configuration from it. This step fails because it tries to find a config file with a name `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe.config` which doesn't exist. None of the project dlls exist in that directory.

I have created an IIS Virtual Directory and checked that the configuration points to the correct physical directory (where my solution is). I also tried incrementing the IISExpress port number by one so that it would create a new virtual directory.

My question is how to find the correct path for the data access dll regardless of the environment I'm in? The `FileConfiguration` helper class uses `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and I'm not sure it it's always applicaple?

If I try to get the Assembly Path directly it will point to some temp directory that doesn't contain the config file.

Comment: Where does the `WebAPI Helper Class` come from?

Comment: It's from the nuget package Microsoft.CrmSdk.WebApi.Samples.HelperCode

Comment: You can only read from `web.config` via the standard way, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can get the path of the IIS application by using `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`.

[How to get ASP.NET application path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233735/how-to-get-asp-net-application-path)